# Why can't I find "ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN" in the Android Developers?

Tags: android

I found this problem in the Android Developers Doc last month, but today I can't find it.

Have any idea can help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be removed from Docs because this is a hidden constant, at least on Android 9:

http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#2638

```
/**
     * Activity Action:  Start this activity to request system shutdown.
     * The optional boolean extra field {@link #EXTRA_KEY_CONFIRM} can be set to true
     * to request confirmation from the user before shutting down. The optional boolean
     * extra field {@link #EXTRA_USER_REQUESTED_SHUTDOWN} can be set to true to
     * indicate that the shutdown is requested by the user.
     *
     * <p class="note">This is a protected intent that can only be sent
     * by the system.
     *
     * {@hide}
     */
    public static final String ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN
            = "com.android.internal.intent.action.REQUEST_SHUTDOWN";
```

Comment: Thanks your info ! Is there any way to use this? Because my customer wants me to provide this feature.

Comment: This is not possible as described at javadoc "This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system", this only available to application compiled with the system with some specifics privileges.

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do about that, this is a security issue of Android. Sorry about that. If you can accept the answer, will be nice

Comment: Of course, I can prove it with my boss and the customer.This can't be done! :)

Comment: @gpppqp glade to help! To accept the answer you have to click on "V" button on left side. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If we want to fire this action with intent, app should be a system app.
This is from Android 11, not sure about other Android versions.

```
 fun shutDownWithoutConfirmation(context: Context) {
        try {
            val intent = Intent("com.android.internal.intent.action.REQUEST_SHUTDOWN")
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", false)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }




fun shutDownWithConfirmation(context: Context) {
        try {
            val intent = Intent("com.android.internal.intent.action.REQUEST_SHUTDOWN")
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", true)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```